# Nhibernate type and Id get form session

Tags: nhibernate

Helo i got Type of object and id how can i get it from nhibernate session?
Example
Type t = Company;
Int id = 100;

getobject(t,id)
change somethings in it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173254/how-to-get-object-from-session-with-unknown-type-and-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some error in code but method now is working for example if we got

Namespace.Company 
Namespace.somefolder.Company 
In this cases it will work ;)

```
       public static Object GetObjectFromSession(object ret, int id)
    {
        string z = ret.GetType().ToString();
        z = z.Substring(z.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        ISession session = GetExistingWebSession();
        ret = session.Get(z, id);
        return ret;
    }

    public static Object GetObjectFromSession(string ret, int id)
    {
        ret = ret.Substring(ret.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        ISession session = GetExistingWebSession();
        return session.Get(ret, id);
    }
```