# How to get object from session with unknown type and id?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

What I'm trying to do is get object data from session.

Code below should make clear all:

```
//Type of object which i need to get in runtime
Type someUnknownType = typeof(someObject);
int id = 1; // for example
// here i got error cannot resolved someUnknownType
ISession.Get<someUnknownType>(id);
```

How can I do that?

**Edit:**
`someObject` is instance variable.

Comment: @abatishchev why u deleted "Thanks for advance?" ?

Comment: Is `someObject` an instance variable or type?

Comment: I've removed that because it's a [common moderation practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) to remove Hello and Thanks, here on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have a mistake:

- if `someObject` is an instance variable, you can't call `typeof(someObject)`. You can only call `someObject.GetType()`
- if it is a type, you still use the generic version.

---

Have you tried to use [non-generic version](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/ISession.cs#L849):

```
object x = ISession.Get(someObject.GetType(), id);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use this Get method:

```
ISession.Get(Type, Object);
```

Here is an example from the [NHibernate documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-loading):

```
Cat cat = (Cat) sess.Get(catInstance.GetType(), id);
```

Comment: IF you know a type, use the generic version - `Get<Cat>()`. If you don't - call `Get(cat.GetType(), id)`

Comment: Fix that, please, and will happy to upvote you :) Because currently it really makes no sense because is opposite to OP's preconditions.